# boost::format() output operator

Tags: c++, string-formatting, boost-format

I need to write the class which will accept **boost::format()** through the operator like **cout** does:

```
cout << boost::format("some string; some param = %d\n") % someValue;
```

Which type of operator's parameter must be?
So that the class will be declared like this:

```
class Output
{
    Output& operator<<(... format);
}
int main()
{
    Output output;
    output << boost::format("...");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::format` is the type you want. It has a `str()` member to get a std::string.

Comment: But I don't understand how **cout** knows about some **boost::format** type?

Comment: @Slav cout _doesn't_ know about some boost::format. In boost there's an operator<< that knows about cout (ostream really) and boost::format. The key is operator<< doesn't need to be a member. The iostream library was designed to be extended for new types this way.

Comment: No. There is no inheritance needed. It's simply another overload of `operator<<`. It will look something like ostream& `operator<<(ostream&  out, const boost::format& fmt) { out << fmt.str(); return fmt; }`. Again, `operator<<` can be a free function, it doesn't have to be a member.